# Can I get into trouble for identifying vulnerabilities in someone elses website?

Tags: security

Is it possible to get into legal trouble for identifying vulnerabilities in a web application even if you don't exploit them?

I have considered using tools like NetSparker on occasion to see if a site has any vulnerabilities and I'd like to contact the owner of the site to see if they'd be interested in me fixing it.  I suspect that some of these people might get angry or misinterpret my intentions and I'm curious if I could get into any trouble for simply finding these security issues.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a legal advice community.

Comment: They'd probably think you're trying to scam them and that you want "protection" money. If you're going to do it, make sure the info you send them is 100% anonymous (or as much as is reasonably possible) so they can't accuse you of trying to scam them. Offering to fix the problem for money? I'd say "don't!".

Comment: @Ben, this seems like the best place to ask this question.  Is there a way that I could rephrase my question that would make it more acceptable in your book?

Comment: I'd just submit a bug report with details for how to reproduce the issue.  There's no way to know if the issue is already fixed in their code, due to codebase updating/etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for vulnerabilities in open source software  or commercially distributed software and you are a US citizen you are protected by the 1st amendment.  It is legal for you to write exploit code and do whatever you want (as long as it isn't selling it to terrorists/the mob).  If you do find a flaw,  [report it](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/post/1) to [BugTraq](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1) and put it on your resume.   I have racked up a lot of CVE numbers over the years and I actively [write exploit code](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:duIsVx8YAw4J:milw0rm.com/author/677+www.milw0rm.com/author/677&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

In [Germany](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2007/08/new_german_hack.html) and France the laws are a bit different,  the possession of "hacking tools" like exploit code or even NMAP can land you in jail.   You might also be interested in [the laws of full disclosure](http://www.securityfocus.com/columnists/466).

On the flip side,  if you go around scanning people's web sties looking for vulnerabilities you are **breaking the law**  and the FBI will investigate you.   **Do not look for vulnerabilities in random websites without the owners permission.**

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any chance you could cite a source for what law this violates.

Comment: You should offer your services as an exploit annalist of sorts and provide them with information on what you will do and how this will save them from problems in the future. Explain cost value here.

Comment: The boldface text bears repeating.  If you use a tool like NetSparker against a site you don't control, you can be charged with a crime in the US (don't know about other countries), and you can go to prison.  Even if you're trying to help.

Comment: @user257493  or how about I just go full disclosure watch a million sites go up in flames,  because that perfectly legal in the US.

Comment: @user257493, I agree this is a good idea.  My thought is that you are much more likely to get a client if you KNOW there is a vulnerability already.  Not worth it if you go to jail i guess...

Comment: @Abe Miessler Your right,  that could be a selling point.  But in practice most people freak out and call the FBI.  I'm not joking,  I have seen people go down this path and get screwed, its not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get into trouble but depending on how big of a prick and who gets embarrassed and who feels threatened you could easily turn into the next [Adrian Lamo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adrian_Lamo).

Comment: Screw Lamo,  that nark should be thrown in jail.

Comment: There's others with similar stories all over the place, I just picked someone who was in the spotlight recently. Yeah, he was involved in wikileaks, but he also helped close a serious exploit that could have brought down most of north america in the proper hands and got in trouble for telling the authorities about it. Remember Captin Crunch? They were afraid he was going to whistle nuclear launch codes into a pay-phone.

Answer (score 0):

What one can get into trouble doing often comes down to what "they" can convince a judge.  It's certainly possible that a company can see such an act as a genuine attack (the wrong person in the company gets the wrong idea and yells loud enough about it) and seek some kind of damages from you.  Just remember that "being right" or "being reasonable" or "making sense" don't really mean much in the US legal system (assuming US here).

That said, as a developer I absolutely encourage vulnerability testing and reporting back to the developer for the product being tested.  But, unfortunately, you should tread carefully.